# What would public opinion be on nukes if there were less than 100 in the world?

Tags: society, alternate-worlds, military

Right now I am writing a story within its own realm, sort of like Strangereal from Ace Combat, but with a total of 9 continents and 136 nations with technology and societal trends comparable to what we will achieve in 2040, nuclear weapons are exceedingly rare and difficult to produce and maintain due to a decreased amount of isotopes worldwide. An event similar to the Red Scare has happened a few generations prior, though that was because the internet was basis for communist propaganda and lead to several nations becoming socialist. The general public does not know the total number of nukes globally and know very little about nukes themselves other than they can kill off a big chunk of a city. But the perpetrator was a parliamentary country using it on a communist enemy. There is a United Nations analog but has the influence of the Legue of Nations in the real world. The primary reaction in question is from a nation simular to the United States but with a military and size of western Eorope as well as  having a more libertarian government.

Comment: Welcome to the site, interesting scenario you have set up there but I am not sure we have enough information to answer your question.  The response of any human will be their own and I have trouble seeing how any mass of humanity could be anything but appalled at the use of a nuclear weapon on a civilian center...

Comment: Check out the [tour] and the [help] to get an understanding of the site and how it functions.  Good luck and enjoy world building.

Comment: A related question would be how much of the public knows how many nuclear warheads are out there?  I don't get the impression that people's opinion of nuclear war is based on numbers of weapons.  It's based on the devastation of each individual.

Comment: If there are so few nukes, there is a massive gap in background where WWII happened and the cold war after. Please provide some background to fill in the blanks we need to provide you with the answer you desire.

Comment: Actually in the real world here and now *"the general public does not know the total number of nukes globally and know very little about nukes themselves other than they can kill off a big chunk of a city"*. This doesn't stop various segments of the public from having strong opinions about nuclear weaponry and nuclear energy in general.

Comment: If you want an empirical answer: Research when the public perception of the number of nukes worldwide was around 150, and what people said about it.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends how heavily the government structure is. If you're talking about something like the U.S. then they would be appalled. If it's like the totalitarian government from George Orwell's *Nineteen Eighty-four*, then the government would brainwash its population into believing it was them. They would change the news stories to say they warned the surrounding populations before then.